# Failing to unrar files

Tags: archive, 7zip, rar

I'm sorry to ask this, but all of the questions along similar lines I could find have been answered by installing unrar/7zip.

So, I received  a  book in the form of a .rar archive of jpegs.  Initially, I tried to uncompress with 7zip from terminal.  It goes through each file in the archive and for each file in the archive, says,

```
Extracting   cover.jpg     Unsupported Method
```

After doing some quick googling, I thought it was due to lack of .rar codecs, as it's not technically freeware or somesuch. 
After installing unrar, from the terminal I run

```
unrar -x Books.rar
```

And it goes through and just says "Failed" in the place of 7zip's "Unsupported Method."

I thought it could be a corrupt file or something, so I had a friend compress a random jpg as .rar and send it to me, and I encountered the same program.
Double clicking it opens unroller, which then promptly closes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, very strange. I've never encountered any problems using unrar.

Comment: I have the same problem. Archive Manager is openning just for a second, and terminal output says `failed`.

Answer (score 16):

Execute following command in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install unace unrar zip unzip p7zip-full p7zip-rar sharutils rar uudeview mpack arj cabextract file-roller
```

Then extract any rar file.

Edit : *rar* is provided in the multiverse component, so you must enable that repository.

Comment: many of those are reporting "no installation candidate" -- did you forget to add a PPA?

Comment: rar is provided in the multiverse component, so you must enable that repository.

Comment: Then you should update your answer to include that

Comment: worked! how annoying that there's one 'unrar' that works and another that doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

Complement your installation of 7zip with `p7zip-rar`, the non-free rar module for p7zip:

`sudo apt-get install p7zip-rar`

Comment: +1. That did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: why does this work? Please explain.

Comment: @amzon-ex, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522958/how-to-use-p7zip-to-open-rar-files

Comment: I had to also install "unrar" for Ark archiver to extract .rar

Answer (score 2):

You can download the latest version off winrar for linux on [their website](https://www.win-rar.com/start.html?L=0).

Then extract it with the following command (this is not a rar archive fortunately)

```
tar xvf rarlinux-x64-6.0.2.tar.gz
```

It creates a folder named `rar`in which there is an executable of the same name. You can use it to decompress your archive.

For example if your archive is in the same folder as the `rar` folder.

```
./rar/rar x Books.rar
```

Remark: you may need to allow execution on the `rar` executable with `chmod a+x rar/rar`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install some non-free packages.

On my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian I did the following:

1. Uncomment the `deb-src` line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
   ```
2. Update

   ```
   # apt update && apt upgrade
   ```
3. Install `unrar-nonfree`

   ```
   # apt-get build-dep unrar-nonfree
   # apt-get source -b unrar-nonfree
   # sudo dpkg -i unrar_5.6.6-1_armhf.deb
   ```
4. Install `p7zip-rar`

   Download the last version from https://packages.debian.org/buster/armhf/p7zip-rar and then run the following:

   ```
   # apt install ./p7zip-rar_16.02-3_armhf.deb
   ```